# How do I debug a shiny app that is deployed on Shinyapps.io

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I have a shiny new application that has a few thousand lines of code and I am unsure where to start looking to fix this bug. My application has an authentication process where once the user is successfully logged in, they are redirected to the website URL. Therefore, the bug does not occur on my local disk but only when launched to shinyapps.io

Below is the error message.

```
2021-09-23T16:26:14.510175+00:00 shinyapps[2015426]: Warning: Error in $: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
2021-09-23T16:26:14.515039+00:00 shinyapps[2015426]:   13: runApp
2021-09-23T16:26:14.515040+00:00 shinyapps[2015426]:   12: fn
2021-09-23T16:26:14.515041+00:00 shinyapps[2015426]:    7: connect$retry
2021-09-23T16:26:14.515041+00:00 shinyapps[2015426]:    6: eval
```

In my code there is no function/variable called "connect".
I apologize for the vagueness of this post, but I am really confused on where to even begin here. Your help is really appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Add logging. Whether you go formal with one of several logging-based packages or just use `message` and `warning` is up to you; if you opt for home-grown `message`, I suggest you add the ability to suppress them (without deleting lines of code) quickly once you've figured out *this* bug.

Comment: hi @r2evans thanks for your input. Would you be able to post a few links that go more indepth with what you are referring to? Thank you kindly

Comment: Uh, really? [`?message`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/message.html), [`?warning`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/warning.html) would be a good start. If you want to learn how to do less-informal logging in your app, when you go to a search engine it often helps to include either `"R"` and/or `"CRAN"` (quotes *required*) in addition to your search topic, for example `"CRAN" logging`.